# How to load a variable form my app into package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I know this sounds as easy as using globals, but I'm not so sure.

Here's my case:

- I have multiple files within `/src` directory of my React app, let's call them `src/a.js`, `src/b.js`,
- every single of these files exports one object which I then use within my app:

`./src/a.js`:

```
export default {
  filename: 'a',
  foo: 'bar',
};
```

`./src/b.js`:

```
export default {
  filename: 'b',
  foo: 'bar',
  blah: 'hah',
};
```

Now I have a command to check whether or not structure of objects within these files match (they are being changed by many developers multiple times a day), so when I do `npm check` in terminal it will return `false` for above input, because `blah` does not exist within two files.

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "check": "node check.js runCheck",
  /.../
}
```

My question is: **how the heck do I load these variables to compare them in `package.json`**?

I have a file called:

`./check.js`:

```
function check(files) {
 // checking files there
};

module.exports.check = check;
```

## Approach #1 - imports

This is a build file, not part of the application itself, so when I try to do:

`./check.js`:

```
import a from './src/a';
import b from './src/b';
```

I'm getting:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

## Approach #2 - require

This is going to cause trouble, because I'm using imports, not modules within my app, therefore doing:

`./check.js`:

```
const a = require('./src/a');
const b = require('./src/b');
```

Returns:

> Error: Cannot find module './src/a'.

Of course I can't do `module.exports` within the `a.js`/`b.js` files, because they're part of my app and they should use exports, I've tried using both `export` and `module.exports`, but it does not work as well and looks shitty.

How do I tackle this? Should I load the files using some file loader, parse it as JSON an then compare? Or maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use something like esm (https://github.com/standard-things/esm) to run node with module support.

It should be as simple as:

`npm install esm`

Then update your package script to be:

`"check": "node -r esm check.js runCheck",`

**Edit** Btw, a very clear and well structured question.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, I tried my best but was a bit afraid the question might be slightly too long, I'm glad it wasn't for you. Your solution works like a charm. I'm not a native English speaker and I'd love to ask you one additional question - how would you look for the answer to that question if in my shoes? I've tried Googling it, browsed trough countless questions on SO, but without luck... I think it's not FE per se, but more like node.js stuff? Anyway, thank you again, it's been really helpful and straightforward!

Comment: Trying to Google the right thing can be tricky :) If it were me I would probably search "node modules import export" and then wade through the first few articles or links. I would not have realized you weren't an English native to be honest, it was well written.